# Auto adjust content to screen size with @media

Tags: html, css, iphone

I'm trying to make my website automatically adjust its content to screen size so if I enter the site from an iPhone or similar the layout should change.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .logo {
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .nav {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 35px;
    }
}
```

When I enter the page on google chrome on my computer the content changes as it should when I reduce the chrome window, but when I enter it from my iPhone 5 the page changes its content according this:

```
@media (min-width: 800px) {
    .nav {
        text-align: right;
        margin-top: -30px;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
    .logo {
        padding-top: 17px;  
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }  
}
```

Am I using the @media wrong or why doesn't the page adjust to my first piece of code when I enter it from my iPhone?

Comment: The iPhone is matching the 800px media query. Try putting the 600px query AFTER the 800px one.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**
Try using Device width

```
@media only screen  
and (min-device-width : 800px) 
{

  .nav {
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    }
.logo {
    padding-top: 17px;  
    padding-bottom: 0;
}  
}
```